# How to double a word using python?

Tags: python, string

This is what I have so far

```
def doubleMirror(source):
  pile=""
  for letter in source:
    pile =letter+pile+letter
  print pile
```

and that comes out looking like this

```
>>> doubleMirror("dogs")
sgoddogs
```

As you can see, the result is just one word mirroring itself, whereas the desired outcome is to have the word repeated and *also* mirroring itself:

```
sgodsgoddogsdogs
```

Comment: Hint: `'dogs'*2` gets you `'dogsdogs'`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating things. I'd just take the input, reverse it and concatinate it twice, and then concatinate to the word itself twice:

```
def doubleMirror(source):
    return (source[::-1] * 2) + (source * 2)
```

Comment: Someone new to Python may be unaware that (1) you can [slice](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) strings using an optional third 'stride' argument, which when negative goes in reverse order, and (2) you can use the `*` operator to repeat a string a fixed number of times.